# MATLAB Cutting .wav file from input difficulties

Tags: matlab, user-interface, audio, input, matlab-guide

I'm experimenting with MATLAB currently and the first part that interested me was sound manipulation. I set out to design an interface so that I can kill two birds with one stone and learn both as I go along.  So far I have been able to get the interface to load a file plot it and then play it all within the interface.

I now want to be able to take inputs from a potential user that will denote two seperate seconds in the sound clip and allow the user to cut that part of the clip out. So they will be left with the original clip/song then a new section from that song/clip. I will then move on to plot this later. My problem is that I am completely stumped on how to get the input from the user and get that to cut the clip.

Below I will show my code to load the file in so you can see the names given and then the code with which I tried to cut the clip.

First, names given(includes plotting)(I also load the file to an audio player):

```
[filename,pathname] = uigetfile('.wav', 'File Selector');
[sound,rate] = audioread([pathname,'/',filename]);
figure = plot(sound)
plot(handles.axes1,sound);
```

My attempt at getting inputs from two edit text boxes:

```
SectionStart = get(handles.SectionStartET, 'string');   
SectionEnd = get(handles.SectionEndET, 'string');
FileSection = FS(SectionStart:SectionEnd);
global player2;
player2 = audioplayer(FileSection);
```

In the first two lines here, I'm getting the string from the edit text boxes. Then I tried to put the two together. Then I load the player. I feel like the syntax is wrong on the third line before the brackets but I can't find a good example online to help, hoping someone here can shed some light! Thanks in advance!

Everyone's viewing but not posting, if you need more info about the code let me know!

Comment: Did you mean `FS(str2num(SectionStart): str2num(SectionEnd));`? If that is not the problem' can you post the error you get\explain why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: Thanks alot for the feedback, I'm UK based so I'm going to try this in the morning I'll give feedback when I've tried. Thanks haha didn't think anyone was ever going to reply!